# How to combine clinical variables?

Tags: chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am dealing with several clinically used variables that are not linked to each others. Those variables are correlated to worsened prognosis (some are numeral and asymmetric, therefore correlations were considered using Mann-Whitney-U, others were nominal variables). All of these variables do have statistical significance and some even high sensitivities, specificities and positive predictive values. But as human lives are considered, there's always need for perfection.

Therefore, I would like to test several combinations of variables. How do I do that elegantly?

Comment: How does one consider correlations using Mann-Whitney? What kind of correlation do you intend?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use _all_ of the variables? For prediction/prognostication, throwing away predictor variables just throws away potentially useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric variables can be analyzed with Principal Components Analysis to see if they measure the same underlying component. Variables that measure the same underlying component as determined by factor loadings in the PCA can be aggregated into a single variable. The identity of the components can be identified by determining what is similar about the variables loading onto the same component. The aggregated score representing a component can then be used in other analyses such as t-tests comparing whether gender influences the aggregated component score.